# How to get the result in a function out in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var data = null;
function dataReal(val) {
  data = JSON.parse(val);
  console.log(data); // Result object : {users: Array(3), permission: Array(8)}
}
console.log(data); // Result : null
```

How do I get that result outside the function : `dataReal`

**Update :**

In file User.vue

```
props: {
    msg: String,
  },
created() {
    const userId = this.$route.params.id;
    axios
      .get("/project/api/users/" + userId)
      .then((res) => {
        dataReal(res.data); // json string
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

In file user.js

```
var data = null;
function dataReal(val) {
  data = JSON.parse(val);
  console.log(data); // Result object : {users: Array(3), permission: Array(8)}

}
dataReal(val) //val is not defined
console.log(data); // 

export { dataReal };
```

Comment: Add `return`  statement in `dataReal`. And Then invoke the function.

Comment: You would need to call `dataReal(someJsonString)` in order for it to alter `data` before that last `console.log(data)` line

Comment: @HassanImam OP isn't trying to use the returned value so that duplicate doesn't apply

Comment: @Phil I thought OP want to access the `data` value outside of function. OP needs to clarify the question.

Comment: @HassanImam they can and are accessing `data` since it's defined outside the function. What they're not doing is calling the `dataReal` function (at least as far as the code in this question goes)

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = null;
function dataReal(val) {
  data = JSON.parse(val);
  console.log(data); // Result object : {users: Array(3), permission: Array(8)}
}
dataReal(val); // Call this function before accessing
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I did so, but got the error: `apiRes is not defined` . outside the function callback

Comment: Are you using any other variable named apiRes ?

Comment: The apiRes variable I pass from the subfile. Here I receive

Comment: It seems the issue is with using the apiRes variable. I need more detail on how apiRes is implemented and used.

Comment: I have edited the question..please review it for me.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you are missing one step here :)

your `data` is `undefined` because you did not invoke the function, so `data` is not assigned properly and remains `null/undefined`

you can try to pass in your parameters into `dataReal`, and then invoke the function after that

```js
var data = null;
function dataReal(val) {
  data = val;
  //console.log(data); // Result object : {users: Array(3), permission: Array(8)}
}

dataReal({users: ["user-1", "user-2", "user-3"], permission: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

console.log(data);
```